# Overwriting Values From SQL Table to Another SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, insert-update, xquery-sql

I have 2 databases, a live and backup. I want to overwrite the the values in a specific field in the live database from those that are in the backup. The database structure is identical the only difference is there name.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have a column that identifies the *rows* where the columns should be matched?

Comment: The databases are called Live & Backup1, the tables are both called order_line_analysis, the columns to update are called ola_m_1

Comment: . . That wasn't my question.  What identifes the matching rows between the rows in the two tables in the two databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE liveDB
  SET column2 = src.column2 -----Whichever column you want
FROM BackupDB.dbo.Table1 AS src
INNER JOIN LiveDB.dbo.Table1 AS dest
ON src.column1 = dest.column1;
```

Updated

```
UPDATE live
SET l.ola_m_1= b.ola_m_1
FROM live.dbo.order_line l
JOIN backup.dbo.order_line b
ON --Whatever is Similar column between two
```

Comment: ok still struggling a bit here. the live database is called live, backups called backup. the table is called order_line_analysis in both databases and the filed is called ola_m_1 I barely know SQL so any extra help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi I just can't get it to work..The databases are called dstgood & dstbad, the tables are both called order_line_analysis, the columns to update are called ola_m_1. dstbad needs updating with data from dstgood